# insert a PDF into another multiple times on linux

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, pdftk

I need help to insert a PDF file every 4 pages of another PDF.

I have 2 files A and B. A is 100 pages, I need to put every 4 pages the entire PDF B which is 4 pages.

I know the pdftk has functions cat and shuffle, but it needs write by hand the consecution, with Adobe Acrobat Pro I woould use a script like this (found on Adobe forum):

```
/* add page after each nth page */
var n = 4;

for (var i=this.numPages-1; i>0; i--) {
    if ((i+1) % n == 0) {
        this.insertPages(i, "/path/to/file.pdf");
    }
}
```

I haven't anymore Adobe Acrobat Pro so I'm looking for a Linux tool.

Thanks.